# Is it normal for winapi to take around 70ms to read from serial port?

Tags: winapi

The true time it takes from when I send the first bit to a serial port to when I receive the last bit it pings back I measured to be 6ms but ReadFile takes around 70-80ms. I'm wondering if this is expected, is this just Windows or is it my code at fault? Here's the function to send and read from the serial port, in my main I have declared and initialized the HANDLE and called that function.

```
int sendBytes(char* command, char* COM, HANDLE hSerial, int read) {
BOOL Write_Status;
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };                    // Initializing DCB structure


dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

Write_Status = GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);     //retreives  the current settings

if (Write_Status == FALSE) {
    printf("\n   Error! in GetCommState()");
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
}


dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;

dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

Write_Status = SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);  //Configuring the port according to settings in DCB

if (Write_Status == FALSE)
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
}

///*----------------------------- Writing a Character to Serial Port----------------------------------------*/
int length = strlen(command);
char send[20];
strcpy(send, command);
send[length + 1] = 13;
send[length + 2] = 10;
DWORD  dNoOFBytestoWrite;              // No of bytes to write into the port
DWORD  dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;          // No of bytes written to the port
dNoOFBytestoWrite = length + 2; // Calculating the no of bytes to write into the port

if (!WriteFile(hSerial, send, dNoOFBytestoWrite, &dNoOfBytesWritten, NULL))
    printf("Error writing text to %s\n", COM);

if (read) {
    int maxChars = 100;
    BOOL  Read_Status;                      // Status of the various operations 
    DWORD dwEventMask;                      // Event mask to trigger
    char  SerialBuffer[100];               // Buffer Containing Rxed Data
    DWORD NoBytesRead;                     // Bytes read by ReadFile()
    ///*------------------------------------ Setting Receive Mask ----------------------------------------------*/

    Read_Status = SetCommMask(hSerial, EV_RXCHAR); //Configure Windows to Monitor the serial device for Character Reception

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
        printf("\n\n    Error! in Setting CommMask");
//  else
//      printf("\n\n    Setting CommMask successfull");


    ///*------------------------------------ Setting WaitComm() Event   ----------------------------------------*/

//  printf("\n\n    Waiting for Data Reception");

    Read_Status = WaitCommEvent(hSerial, &dwEventMask, NULL); //Wait for the character to be received

    // /*-------------------------- Program will Wait here till a Character is received ------------------------*/

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf("\n    Error! in Setting WaitCommEvent()");
    }
    else //If  WaitCommEvent()==True Read the RXed data using ReadFile();
    {
    //  printf("\n\n    Characters Received \t");

        clock_t begin = clock();
        if (!ReadFile(hSerial, SerialBuffer, 24, &NoBytesRead, NULL))
        {
            printf("wrong character");
            return 1;
        }
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("time : %f\n",time_spent);



    }
}

}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you if your code is at fault if you didn't post your code?

Comment: You don't need to use `WaitCommEvent`.  Use `SetCommTimeouts()` (once, when opening port) and then just call `ReadFile()` when you need incoming data.

Comment: No, that is not normal.  For one, ReadFile does not wait for the "last bit to be pinged back", it returns whatever happens to be available in the driver's receive buffer.  But we don't know the driver, and USB is always around to obfuscate what's going on with its packet-based transfer mode, and anti-malware is always very interested in ReadFile calls from an executable file that appeared from seemingly nowhere.  So its not like we couldn't find a reason that doesn't help you.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah it turned out to be the device itself, or rather the converters and hub. I plugged in the device directly to my pc and measured fast read speeds, around 2,3 ms

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you measure timing with sub-second precision:

```
    clock_t begin = clock();
    // stuff
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

This is how you measure timing:

```
    LARGE_INTEGER before, after, frequency;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&before);
    // stuff
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&after);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    double time_spent = (after.QuadPart - before.QuadPart) / (double)frequency.QuadPart;
```

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is imprecise, and then `clock()` can be even worse, often as bad as the scheduler quantum which is typically 10ms or 15ms.

Comment: Indeed, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` evaluates to 1000 in Microsoft's Universal CRT, so the resolution is no better than 1ms. As an alternative, you could use [high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) or [steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) with C++. Either one uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` in Microsoft's [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/3d145adb3c219bc9ad88161c87e2b89f52e9acdd/stl/inc/chrono#L709).